# Problem logging into admin

Tags: admin, cookie, magento-1.4

I'm having issues with a clone of our production store (Mag v1.4.0.1). We cloned our production store to a staging server for testing some modifications and I cannot login to the staging server's admin portal. Please don't berate me for having such an old version, ours is heavily modified and we cannot upgrade.

We have done this many times and never had an issue. I made the required changes to the database as shown below, but I keep getting redirected to the main page of our production store. I also toally cleared the store/var/cache and store/var/session directories and made sure the store/var directory was chmod 777. We DO NOT have SSL on this server and it has never caused an issue before.

Also, the cookies are getting stored with www.scic.com and scic.com domains. I do not see any cookies with staging.cic.scic.com in them anywhere.

What am I missing???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a while back - These steps fixed it for me

1)In PHPMyADMIN run this query:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

2) Clear /var/cache/* and /var/session/*

3) Clear your browser cache/cookies

If that doesn't work make sure session and cache directories are writeable

Comment: If you had read my post totally, you would have seen that I already did all that.

Comment: Apologies but not sure where in the original post are the queries on the database  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Just trying to help

Comment: I checked the values in the database. they are correct. That is insignificant.

Comment: By not being appreciate of someone's help, you're not encouraging anyone else to bother helping, either.